# Extjs удалить hover css class

Tags: extjs

Нужно удалить :hover css класс с определенной колонки. Во всех остальных колонках этот класс нужен. Возможно поставить filter на css класс нужной колонке?

Answer (score 0):

С возможностью переопределения стилей в указанной колонке.

if (colIndex = n)
    meta.style += 'My style с !important'